# Unexpected end of JSON input error in Post request on api using access token in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am posting the details of user in api ,using the access token in header which i got in sign up but getting this error --> Unexpected end of JSON input. My code is

```
     postNameToApi() 
        {

        console.log("inside post api");
        fetch('https://MyPostApi', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Authorization':'Bearer'+'Qwjubq41KAWw9uI2NMj4TPQ9t24PxC'
                },


          body: JSON.stringify({
          dob:'1992-04-18',
          gender: 'femanino',
          is_professional:true,
          is_referee:false

        })
           }).then((response) => response.json())
             .then((responseData) => {
                                console.log("inside responsejson");
                                console.log('response:',responseData);

                       //this.setState({response:responseData});
         }).done();
     }
```

Comment: Did you check whether the response is OK at all (or a 403)? Did you check whether the response body is JSON? What does the the network panel of your devtools say about the response?

Comment: yes I did. @Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your response is not in json format. Space is missing between Bearer and your token, i think this will solve your issue.

```
'Authorization':'Bearer '+'Qwjubq41KAWw9uI2NMj4TPQ9t24PxC'
```

Try your api call with [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) first.

Comment: Please explain why the missing space causes the response format to change.